# Random ClassCastExceptions to apparently random views using findViewById

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, classcastexception, layout-inflater

I don’t consider myself an experienced developer, but I can say that I’m experienced enough to avoid `ClassCastException`s on views: I **know** which view is linked to which id in my layout.

What’s happening is that I’m getting silly crashes along the line of:

```
TextView v = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
ClassCastException: cannot cast AppCompatImageView to TextView
```

in different parts of the app, but **not in a reproducible way** (it doesn’t happen every time I do that particular action). This is driving me crazy!

### Examples

```
// IN A AppCompatDialogFragment
// R.layout.sheet_menu is a frame with only two childs:
// a TextView and a RecyclerView.

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sheet_menu, container, false);
}    

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_sheet_title);
    list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_sheet_list);

    // CLASSCASTEXCEPTION! Cannot cast AppCompatTextView to RecyclerView!
}
```

And another:

```
// IN A RECYCLERVIEW ADAPTER
// Inflating the view holder layout with
// View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.editable_story, null);

private class EditableStoryHolder extends PrimaryHolder {

    public EditableStoryHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ...
        likes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes_count);

        // CLASSCASTEXCEPTION! Cannot cast AppCompatImageView to TextView
    }
```

## Double Checked

I’m never explicitly calling `removeView` or anything else

- I am importing the right package `R` class
- The ids I’m using are **unique** in all the project, and I’m pretty sure they are not used inside any of my dependencies

So, what’s happening? Why does findViewById return the wrong child? I’m testing on API23, using support libraries v. 23.2.1. This is a pretty new issue. Something wrong with the appcompat layout inflater?

Comment: Did you try rebuilding or cleaning the project? The problem sure seems odd (in a corrupt project sort of way ;))

Comment: @mjp66 I’ll try again. However, a corrupted R file would cause a crash 100% of times, I’d say...

Comment: Are you using proguard? multi-dex or other compiler options?

Comment: @greywolf82 nope, nothing strange.

Comment: Maybe you need to use proguard for shrinking, if you hit dex size limits strange things can happen

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the generated R file becomes out of sync (not sure why but I experience this issue often)

Simply clean the project by selecting Build -> Clean Project

This should regenerate the R files and solve the issue, you may have to clean the project everytime you add a new view to a layout

Comment: I had tried before.. And I can’t even say if this is the solution, because the issue is not easily reproducible :\

Comment: Not sure what causes it, but I have a project that I have to clean before every build or findViewById() returns the wrong child

Comment: I say everytime, I mean everytime I add a new view to a layout

Answer (score 0):

Did you introduce library that will affect the LayoutInflater or related factories? Make sure the inflater create a correct view. I think you can debug into LayoutInflater.java to make sure everything works correctly.